# using jade mixins in node.js code

Tags: node.js, pug

I try to use `jade` in node.js code

```
 var jade = require ('jade');
 var jadeString =  "include '../views/mixins/mixinFile.jade'\n"+ "mixin mixinName(arg)";
 var html = jade.compile (jadeString);
```

But got error:

```
Error: Jade:1
  > 1| include '../views/mixins/mixinFile.jade'
    2| mixin mixinName(arg)

the "filename" option is required to use "include" with "relative" paths
```

I tried different **relative** paths. All the time got this error. How to know what is my current path to include relative jade path correctly?